# Measuring angle based on optic fibre extension, tricky geometry problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

For an experiment, I am trying to make use of an optic fibre to measure the angle of a mirror along the vertical axis. Simplifying to a two-dimensional slice, this mirror (line $S$) is connected to a fixed pivot on its top end, allowing free movement (between $-90^o$ and $+90^o$ degrees). The other bottom end is connected to optic fibre $l$ and another fixed pivot on the same vertical line as the first. Let the angle $\alpha$ be defined as the angle between $S$ and the vertical axis. For $\alpha = 0$, let the length of the optic fibre $l$ be $L$. For any other angle $\alpha$, let the length be $L+\Delta L$, with varying $\Delta L$ for varying $\alpha$. I wish to express this angle $\alpha$ in terms of $L, S$ and $\Delta L$. Please see the image below for a diagram I created in Geogebra. Here, I show circle segments for the movement of $S$ and $L$ with the extension of $\Delta L$ up until it connects to $S$. Some guidelines with horizontal perpendicular lines are drawn.

[image: Diagram of set-up]

I have crunched a lot of trigonometry rules, Pythagoras, making use of areas and the composition of the triangles with guidelines, congruency and positioning it on a graph using functions, but I cannot seem to find an expression for $\alpha$ without any other variables than $S, L$ and $\Delta L$. Would anyone be able to help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you essentially have a triangle with sides $S+L, S, L+\Delta L$? If so , this should be enough to figure out all angles using the Law of cosines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use cosine rule :

$$(L+\Delta L)^2=s^2+(L+s)^2- 2 s(L+s) \cos \alpha$$

from which :

$$\alpha = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{s^2+(L+s)^2-(L+\Delta L)^2}{2 s(L+s)}\right) $$

Comment: I feel so defeated by your simple answer, lol. This was so utterly easy indeed. Coincidentally, I have used the Law of cosines on smaller triangles I drew in this one, but I was utterly oblivious to the bigger picture to do it in one go. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for your thanks !